# Nutch 2.1 - generator job runtime exception job failed

Tags: java, apache, nutch

I am getting the below error when i try to generate urls using the generate command:

> GeneratorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=generate: 1357474131-234134646, jobid=job_local_0001
>           at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:191)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.generate(GeneratorJob.java:213)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:241)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.main(GeneratorJob.java:249)

The `generate`, `fetch` and `parse` were working fine, but `updatedb` was giving this error before sometimes:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=update-table, jobid=job_local_0001
>       at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.run(DbUpdaterJob.java:98)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.updateTable(DbUpdaterJob.java:105)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.run(DbUpdaterJob.java:119)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.main(DbUpdaterJob.java:123)

Now, it is continuously giving generate job failed. What might be the issue? Can it be mysql issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above errors are due to insufficient space on the partition on the server where i have installed . check the answer at [Insufficient space for shared memory file when i try to run nutch generate command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290504/insufficient-space-for-shared-memory-file-when-i-try-to-run-nutch-generate-comma/14290628)